# How to invoke a method on specific running task

Tags: c#, methods, task, invoke, taskscheduler

I'm new in the themes tasks.

How to get access to the right task and invoke the method on this task? The task has an ID and I gave a Name to it and I got a TaskScheduler.

I get the Exception, which is correct:
InvalidOperationException: The calling thread can not access this object because the object is owned by another thread.

Problem:
In the Main I start a Task with CustomSplashScreenViewModel.StartSplashScreenAsync(). More Tasks get startet and are running. With the Event when everything has loaded I need to Close my SplashScreen.

The method CustomSplashScreenViewModel.CloseSplash(_splashTask, _taskSchedulerSplash); get those informations. When I debug it, the _splashTask is "null" and in the _taskSchedulerSplash it has the _splashTask inside. 
Inside the CloseSplash Method I like to invoke the method _view.Close() on the _splashTask.

How do I solve this?

```
public class Program
{
  private static readonly SingleThreadTaskScheduler _taskSchedulerSplash = new SingleThreadTaskScheduler(ApartmentState.STA);

  [ThreadStatic]
  private static Task _splashTask;

//        [STAThread]
  public static async Task Main()
  {       
    _splashTask = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        return CustomSplashScreenViewModel.StartSplashScreenAsync();
    }, _taskSchedulerSplash);

    var taskScheduler = new SingleThreadTaskScheduler(ApartmentState.STA);
    var taskList = new List<Task>(); 

    var updateTask = Task.Run(InstallHelper.CheckForUpdatesAsync);
    updateTask.Wait();
    taskList.Add(updateTask);

    var tasks = await Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(taskList.ToArray(), result => Task.Factory.StartNew( ()=>AppStart(container), taskScheduler));
        tasks.Wait();
   }


   private static void App_MainWindowLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     CustomSplashScreenViewModel.CloseSplash(_splashTask, _taskSchedulerSplash);
   }
}

public class CustomSplashScreenViewModel
{
  private static Thread _currentThread;
  public static void CloseSplash(Task task, TaskScheduler taskScheduler)
  {
    if (_view!= null)
    {
      // Here i need the right Task and to invoke the following method
      // if I'm doing _view.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(_view.Close)); it doesn't 
      // work coz it's another STA Thread. Inside this class I can store the right task in 
      // a local variable. this works. But how to invoke it if the Task is already running?
      // I like to overgive the task - may it isn't possible. 
      _view.Close();      
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a running task. However, you can schedule *another* task that will run on the same scheduler, which should work just fine for what you need (it'll run on the same STA thread that owns the splash screen):

```
public static void CloseSplash(Task task, TaskScheduler taskScheduler)
{
  if (_view!= null)
  {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _view.Close(), taskScheduler);
  }
}
```

On a side note, I'd recommend these to make the code easier to understand:

1. Introducing a `TaskFactory` instance for your custom task scheduler instead of using `TaskScheduler` with `Task.Factory`.
2. Avoid `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll` and `Task.Wait`; use `Task.WhenAll` and `await` instead.